# How do you stop old Firestore updates from overwriting new local data?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Currently using AngularFire2, I have a setup like this:

```
item: Item;
this.afs.doc(`items/itemX`).valueChanges().subscribe((item: Item) => {
  this.item = item;
}

itemChanged() {
  this.afs.doc(`items/itemX`).update(this.item);
}
```

When I change the value of `this.item` and save it all is good and it works. But it may be clear to see what happens if I quickly change `this.item` multiple times - Sometimes the most recent changes to get overwritten.

How do we avoid this?

Comment: That depends a bit on what behavior you want. If user A and user B both change the same item within milliseconds, and there no way to synchronize the changes from A to B in time, what should the result be?

Comment: That happens sometimes too. I'm ok with the most recent overwriting the other. But in my case I'm talking about just one user. In this case I'll make an update, then another update, and the newest `item` would get overwritten by the original update... not sure how clear that is lol